# how to show busy/working/loading dialog with dynamic message

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jdialog

i want to show modal dialog, which will block my main window and i want to control it from outside by methods showLoadingDialog(), hideLoadingDialog() and setLoadingMessage(String message) - i tried this code, but its not working - Loading dialog is visible, but without message

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LoadingExample {


private static class LoadingDialog extends JDialog {

private JLabel label = new JLabel("working");

public LoadingDialog(JFrame owner) {

    super(owner, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    setUndecorated(true);
    add(label);
    pack();

    // move window to center of owner
    int x = owner.getX()
        + (owner.getWidth() - getPreferredSize().width) / 2;
    int y = owner.getY()
        + (owner.getHeight() - getPreferredSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);



    repaint();


}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    label.setText(message);
}


}



private static LoadingDialog loadingDialog;


public static void main(String[] args) {


final JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Main frame");
mainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));


for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

    final int workTime = i;

    JButton workButton = new JButton("work for " + i + " second");

    //action listener, which had to show loading dialog and countdown seconds before finish
    workButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        showLoadingDialog(mainWindow);

        for (int j = 0; j < workTime; j++)
        try {

            // ... do some work here

            setLoadingMessage("remain " + (workTime - j)
                + " second(s)");
            loadingDialog.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        hideLoadingDialog();
    }
    });


    mainWindow.add(workButton);

}

mainWindow.pack();
mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



mainWindow.setVisible(true);

}




public static void showLoadingDialog(JFrame owner) {
if (loadingDialog != null)
    loadingDialog.dispose();



loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(owner);

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    loadingDialog.setVisible(true);
    };
}.start();

}

public static void setLoadingMessage(String message) {
loadingDialog.setMessage(message);
}


public static void hideLoadingDialog() {

if (loadingDialog != null) {
    loadingDialog.setVisible(false);
    loadingDialog.dispose();
    loadingDialog = null;
}


}

}
```

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: "*i tried this code, but its not working*" - what's not working? You could use a `SwingWorker` that will perform a task in the background and then update the GUI (i.e. message and possibly progress bar) to reflect its progress.

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: if i get it right, SwingWorker can help me to do task in background, but i want to block ui during working, because some other part of application. Or do you suggest to use SwingWorker for showing LoadingDialog? then how can looks these methods methods showLoadingDialog(), hideLoadingDialog() and setLoadingMessage(String message)? thanks :)

Comment: A modal dialog blocks the UI, so what it the problem ? The suggestion is to use a SwingWorker to perform the calculation in the background, and update the state of the modal dialog on the EDT

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make changes to the GUI from a different thread than the dispatcher thread associated to the control you are trying to change. To do this correctly you can use `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater`:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              loadingDialog.setVisible(true);
           }
       });

    };
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write some sample code, but before firing up my IDE I did a small search in the excellent [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and behold, it contains exactly the sample code you are looking for. What you have is a ['task that has interim results'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html). So when you have intermediate results, you call the `SwingWorker#publish` method. In the `SwingWorker#process` method, you update the modal dialog with the new message you just published. The `SwingWorker#done` method allows you to remove the modal dialog afterwards.

But I suggest you read that whole concurrency tutorial from start to finish as your sample code shows you lack some basic Swing threading knowledge.